# Cannot retrieve data into Jtextfield from MySql Database

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench, netbeans-8

```
 try
                    {
                        st=cn.createStatement();
                        String strUser="";
                        rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM chsl_db WHERE name='"+nametxt.getText()+"'");
                        while(rs.next())
                        {
                            strUser=rs.getString(1);
                        }
                        if(strUser.equals(nametxt.getText()))
                        {
                        st= cn.createStatement();
                        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM chsl_db WHERE name ='" + nametxt.getText() + "'");
                        while (rs.next()) 
                        {
                            titletxt.setText(rs.getString(1));
                            nametxt.setText(rs.getString(2));
                            flatnum.setText(rs.getString(3));
                            areatxt.setText(rs.getString(4));
                            emailtxt.setText(rs.getString(5));
                            deletebutton.setEnabled(true);
                        }

                        st.close();
                        }
                            else
                            {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No Data Found!","Security Warning",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                                    }

                                    }

    catch(SQLException s)
    {
        System.out.println("No record found!\n\n\n");
        System.out.println("SQL Error" + s.toString() + " " + s.getErrorCode() + " " + s.getSQLState());
    }
catch(Exception x)
    {
        System.out.println("Error" + x.toString()+" " + x.getMessage());
    }   

}
```

Project on Netbeans Using MySql Workbench as Database. Insert Data into Database is Working but cannot retrieve the same. It throws error "No Data Found!". Checked the connection and its ok. Below are the codes that i used to establish connection. Please Help !!

```
try
    {
        Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
        cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/avinash?useSSL=false","root","password");
    }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException e)  
            {
        System.err.println("Failed to load driver");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
            {
        System.err.println("Unable to connect");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code for Stack Overflow questions. It's indented unreadably at the moment. Next, stop building queries like that - use `PreparedStatement` and parameterized SQL instead; your current approach is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks and conversion failures.

Comment: `strUser` will always contain the name of the last row from the db, not everything.

Comment: Also, you should use a preparred statement to guard against a sql injection

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry about the formatting. Next i will keep that in mind.

Comment: Well you can edit it now rather than waiting until next time...

Comment: @rabbitguy  thanks. It was just silly mistake

Comment: @JonSkeet sir i would have done but stuck in some other error. Hope you dont mind and willing help from you in future

Comment: I don't see how having a different error means you can't format your code for this question...

Answer (score 0):

add `st=cn.createStatement();` in your connection after line below.

```
cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/avinash?useSSL=false","root","password");
```

i don't get in what you need to do.

but i think in beginning would be

```
try {
   nm = nametxt.getText();
if(nm != '') {
   rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM chsl_db WHERE name ='" + nm + "'");
while (rs.next()) {
   titletxt.setText(rs.getString(1));
   nametxt.setText(rs.getString(2));
   flatnum.setText(rs.getString(3));
   areatxt.setText(rs.getString(4));
   emailtxt.setText(rs.getString(5));
   deletebutton.setEnabled(true);
}
 st.close();
 }
 else {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No Data Found!","Security Warning",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
 }
}
```

its been a while i'm not using Netbeans. So tell me if i was wrong.

Comment: actually the mistake was in just one number.In strUser=rs.getString(1); instead of 1 it should be 2